# String contains invalid or unsupported UTF8 codepoints. Bad UTF8 hex sequence: 81 (error 3). while using insert into statement?

Tags: database, analytics, amazon-redshift

redshift code description : The UTF-8 single-byte character is out of range. The starting byte must not be 254, 255 or any character between 128 and 191 (inclusive).

Solutions are provided with Copy Command
error: String contains invalid or unsupported UTF8 codepoints. Bad UTF8 hex sequence: 81 (error 3)
       at Connection.parseE (E:\PS\staging-m-BK\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:539:11)
       at Connection.parseMessage (E:\PS\staging-m-BK\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:366:17)
       at Socket. (E:\PS\staging-m-BK\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:105:22)
       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
       at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
       at TCP.onread (net.js:547:20)
     name: 'error',
     length: 188,
     severity: 'ERROR',
     code: '22021',
     detail: undefined,
     hint: undefined,
     position: undefined,
     internalPosition: undefined,
     internalQuery: undefined,
     where: undefined,
     schema: undefined,
     table: undefined,
     column: undefined,
     dataType: undefined,
     constraint: undefined,
     file: '/home/ec2-user/padb/src/pg/src/backend/utils/adt/varchar.c',
     line: '401',
     routine: 'varcharin' } }

Comment: the error is self explanatory. please can you update your question to show the value that you have as hex?

Comment: no i cant but i want to know do i have  to remove that characters which are creating problem from my string ??

Comment: please update your question with the exact insert statement that you are running.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you will have to remove the bad data in order to load it into Redshift. You can use the `iconv` utility to check files for validity.

```
$ iconv -f UTF-8 your_file -o /dev/null
```

I experienced this when exporting to UTF8 from SQL Server. If you are doing the same then be aware that Redshift can now load the UTF16 output that SQL Server exports by default.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-encoding